# Establishing compute node problem faced off

Tags: 12.04, python, openstack

I am going to establish a compute node on a Ubuntu virtual machine.

I'm following the steps as written on [Configure a Compute node - OpenStack Installation Guide for Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS)  - havana](https://web.archive.org/web/20150921072854/http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/nova-compute.html)

I am stuck on `apt-get install nova-compute-kvm python-guestfs`

I am receiving the error message:

```
Package python-guestfs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
E:Package 'python-guestfs' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do to make the installation succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this package is available in the [Universe Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-guestfs).

First, try to run `apt-get update` to make sure that you have information about the latest packages. If you are still not able to install it after running apt-get update then it is possible that you may not have this repo enabled on your server.

You can check to see if this repository is enabled by running the following command in a terminal:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep universe
```

The output of this command should look something like this:

```
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
```

If you get no output, then add the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
```

If the output is commented out with `#` then remove the comments from `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Then you should be able to run `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install python-guestfs`

Comment: first of all hi.. thank you for your straightforward and nicely explained answer... just one thing... shall I delete previously listed links in sources.list

Comment: No, you need those too. :) If you didnt have the universe repo just add it, leave everything else alone.